# A logic problem: What question should the princess ask?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hello can somebody confirm if my solution to this problem is correct.

The question: A princess visits an island inhabited by two tribes. Members of one tribe
always tell the truth, and members of the other tribe always lie.They only
answers questions by ”yes” or ”no”.
The princess comes to a fork in the road. She needs to know which way (left
or right) leads to the castle where the prince is held captive. She knows that
the other way leads to a fire-breathing dragon but she do not know which way
is which.
Standing at this fork in the road is a member of each tribe, but the princess
can’t tell which tribe each of them belongs to. She picks one of the tribe
members at random and asks a question. What question should she ask in
order to find out which is the way to the castle and how should she interpret
the answer she gets?
Note that there are four possible cases: The way to the castle is either to the
left or to the right, and the person she asks is either the truth-teller or the liar.
Your solution should show, using a table of truth values, that the princess can
always deduce from the answer which is the way to the castle.

My solution:  Let's call the person she asks Person A, and the other person Person B. There are four possible cases:

A is a truth-teller and the way to the castle is to the left.
In this case, if she were to ask B which way leads to the castle, B would lie and say "right". So when she asks A what B would say, A will truthfully say "right". Therefore, the castle is to the left.

A is a truth-teller and the way to the castle is to the right.
In this case, if she were to ask B which way leads to the castle, B would truthfully say "right". So when she asks A what B would say, A will truthfully say "right". Therefore, the castle is to the right.

A is a liar and the way to the castle is to the left.
In this case, if she were to ask B which way leads to the castle, B would truthfully say "left". So when she asks A what B would say, A will lie and say "right". Therefore, the castle is to the left.

A is a liar and the way to the castle is to the right.
In this case, if she were to ask B which way leads to the castle, B would lie and say "left". So when she asks A what B would say, A will truthfully say "left". Therefore, the castle is to the right.

To summarize, regardless of whether A is a truth-teller or a liar, the answer she gets will always point to the correct direction of the castle. The table of truth values is as follows:

A is truth-teller   B says "left"   B says "right"
A says "left"   Impossible  Castle is left
A says "right"  Castle is right Impossible
A is liar   B says "left"   B says "right"
A says "left"   Castle is left  Impossible
A says "right"  Impossible  Castle is right
Therefore, by asking this question, the princess can determine the way to the castle regardless of the tribe of the person she asks.

Comment: They can't answer left/right, only yes/no. Apart from that, it is a correct answer.

Comment: Now the same problem with a prince...

Comment: Try on puzzle.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is the most famous of the [Knights and Knaves problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_and_Knaves) and is well documented online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, your answer is mostly correct, except that you have to ask something like “Would $B$ answer ‘yes’ if I asked them whether the castle is to the left?” because they only answer “yes” or “no”.

Note that this isn’t the only way to solve the question (though I think it’s the most popular one).

For instance, you could also ask either of them “Would *you* answer ‘yes’ if I asked you whether the castle is to the left?”, and you’d get “yes” iff the castle is to the left.

More generally, any question works for which you know the parity of the number of lies involved. In your case, you know that exactly one lie is involved, and in the above example, either $0$ or $2$ lies are involved. So for instance you could ask $A$ “Would $B$ answer ‘yes’ if I asked $B$ whether you would answer ‘yes’ if I asked you whether $B$ would answer ‘yes’ if I asked them whether the castle is to the left”, because this is known to involve $2$ lies, so again you’d get “yes” iff the castle is to the left.

Comment: If you hate hypotheticals, "Is it the case that either you are a truth teller and the castle is to the right or you are a liar and the castle is to the left?" will get yes if and only if the castle is to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the correct answer would be:

"If I were to ask the other person which way leads to the castle, would they say 'yes'?"

Using the same four possible cases, we can determine the correct direction of the castle:

A is a truth-teller and the way to the castle is to the left. In this case, if she were to ask B if the other person would say "yes", B would lie and say "no". So when she asks A, A will truthfully say "yes". Therefore, the castle is to the left.

A is a truth-teller and the way to the castle is to the right. In this case, if she were to ask B if the other person would say "yes", B would truthfully say "yes". So when she asks A, A will truthfully say "yes". Therefore, the castle is to the right.

A is a liar and the way to the castle is to the left. In this case, if she were to ask B if the other person would say "yes", B would truthfully say "yes". So when she asks A, A will lie and say "no". Therefore, the castle is to the left.

A is a liar and the way to the castle is to the right. In this case, if she were to ask B if the other person would say "yes", B would lie and say "no". So when she asks A, A will truthfully say "no". Therefore, the castle is to the right.

To summarize, by asking the question "If I were to ask the other person which way leads to the castle, would they say 'yes'?", the princess can determine the way to the castle regardless of whether A is a truth-teller or a liar. The table of truth values is as follows:

A is truth-teller B says "yes" B says "no" A says "yes" Impossible Castle is left A says "no" Castle is right Impossible A is liar B says "yes" B says "no" A says "yes" Castle is left Impossible A says "no" Impossible Castle is right

Therefore, the princess can always deduce from the answer which is the way to the castle.